# Alert Dialog preference not saving

Tags: java, android, dialog, alert, android-preferences

So i have this `AlertDialog` that pops up and says something right as the user first opens the app.

And then they have the option of clicking a `CheckBox` and disabling the dialog pop up the next time the app launches.

Enabling the `CheckBox` is not working correctly. when the app is closed fully down and then restarted it pops up the alert dialog again. Does anyone see anything wrong with what i have done?

```
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
 public CheckBox dontShowAgain;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    dontShowAgain = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
    adb.setMessage("My Customer Alert Dialog Message Body");



    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {

       //CheckBox Confirm for Alert Dialog
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

         String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
       if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())  checkBoxResult = "checked";
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult); 

            // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
    return; 
      }
   });

      adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)  {

                             // Action for 'Cancel' Button
                        String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
                            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())  checkBoxResult = "checked";
                            SharedPreferences settings =    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                                    editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);    
                        // Commit the edits!
                        editor.commit();
                          return;
                    }
    });

                    //Preferences For Alert Dialog
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
           if (skipMessage !=("checked") )
           adb.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
           adb.show();

   }
```

Here below is my `AlertDialog` XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="5px" />

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Do Not Show Me This Again" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you clean up the indentation please? It's difficult to work through. Also, when you say it doesn't work is there an error or just a lack of results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I see there is that you should not be using == or != on Strings. Instead, use .equals, so it's be

```
if( !skipMessage.equals("checked") )
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that doesn't happen if the preference `skipMessage` is "checked" is setting the icon to R.drawable.icon. Put the `adb.show()` into the if statement too (surround it with curly brackets).

```
if (!skipMessage.equals("checked") ) {
    adb.show();
}
```

Comment: I have cleared it up guys, sorry about the indentation, hopefully its easier to read.

Comment: could you refference what that would look like, should it be like this `if (skipMessage !=("checked") adb.show() )`

Comment: See my edit. @Alex is also right, you can't use != to compare strings. And really you don't need to bother building the alert dialog at all if the value is checked. You could put all of that code within the curly brackets of the if statement (or refactor it in a better way).

Comment: Would you be able to show me what you mean by editing the above code if that isnt to much to ask, im having trouble figuring out what you mean. i understand that if the box is check by create the alert dialog, however would do you mean put the code within curly brackets, or if statment, could you write a little example. By the way, yours and @Alex did resolve me issue with the preferences saving. Thanks